# Java package structure convention

Tags: java

I was working with Typescript and Javascript and I stopped for a bit thinking about namespaces and how we organize code in Java.

Now, pretty often I see multiple classes with the same purpose, just for use with different data, being placed in different packages with different names.

While placing those classes in different packages is a good practice to maintain the project/module in a good state, why would we have to give them different names? I mean, their purpose is the same.

I can answer this question myself: because often we use those classes inside the same unit and they would clash, thus requiring a long full package specification for one or the other.

But aren't we violating the DRY principle? We should use our directory (package) structure to understand in which domain space those classes works.

As I wrote above, I suppose many developers aren't respecting this DRY principle just to avoid long package names. Then, why are we creating those monstruos package hierarchies?
Googling `"Java packages best practices"` results in suggestions such as:

```
com.mycompany.myproduct.[...]
```

Where do those suggestions come from? Aren't we just wasting space?
We obviously do not want to write that every time.

```
MyClass myInstance;
com.mycompany.myproduct.mypackage.MyClass myOtherInstance;
```

But it could have been

```
myfeature.MyClass myInstance
myotherfeature.MyClass myInstance;
```

We could even specify the full package for both.
So, where do those best practices come from?

As it has been said, this convention dates back to the first releases of Java.
Name clashes could be easily solved by qualifying the imported dependency (such as a classpath library) classes with their **short** packages' hierarchy, emphasizing and keeping cleaner **our** own code. It is also important to remember we have access to the package-level visibility, which seems overlooked nowdays.

Comment: The "reverse domain" name part of the convention is an attempt to make it globally unique, so you don't have name clashes with libraries, etc. And if you think just using `myfeature` would be unique enough even within a single company, then I'd think you've only worked for (very) small companies ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks Mark. While I understand what you're saying, I find it pretty nonsense. Isn't it just an established bad habit?

Comment: For the small company, actually the opposite, and yeah I saw that package structure abuse often. If we're talking about modules, then a module should represent a single feature, so no name clashing. Part of the problem come from us not thinking hard enough about what we are doing and the domain we are working on

Comment: Sure, this convention has less value for end-products than for (public) libraries. Companies probably also use the convention for internal products to establish ownership. In any case, your question itself is 'primarily opinion-based'. But if you want a source, look no further than Sun (now Oracle): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html I think this convention was already established with the initial release of Java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right Mark. I understand it being opinion-based. I'll leave it there for a couple of hours and then I'll close it myself. I would like to receive some more inputs : )

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, I had read it, but as you can see their packages begin with `java`, which is a feature. Some packages are Sun related, such as `sun.misc.Unsafe` but it is pretty short indeed, and still feature oriented.

Comment: The code might be part of a monolithic app which leads to any particular developer not being aware of similar code already existing somewhere else in the app, or the developer is aware of similar code but decides (for whatever reason) not to create a package intended for use across features/domains and refactor the code.  The side effect is nearly duplicate code in packages like com.mycompany.business.area.feature1.util and com.mycompany.business.area.feature2.util.

Comment: It's also important to remember package visibility exists for a reason. A pity developers forget it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter points out, this convention was established at the very beginning of Java, to allow a global namespace to be used for all classes.

One thing about Java that influences this -- and is different from TypeScript and JavaScript -- the name of a class **and its package** (as well as all the names of classes and packages it uses) is fixed at **compile time**. You can't recombine classes into a different hierarchy without modifying their source code. So it's not as flexible as an interpreted language where you can just move the hierarchy around and change the locations from which you load code.

You can, of course, put everything in your application in the top-level package, for example, and be pretty confident you'll get away with it. You'll be able to do that as long as everyone *else* follows the existing convention. Once they stop doing that, and libraries start putting classes wherever they want, you'll have collisions, and you'll have to change your application. Or libraries will start colliding with each other, and if you don't have the source, you won't really be able to fix it.

So there are good reasons.

My opinion-based part of this -- sticking with conventions and a language's (or platform's) culture makes sense. Even if the conventions are silly, in our view. There's a place for breaking them but the advantages have to be pretty big. Other developers will be used to the convention, tools will make assumptions about the conventions ... usually it makes sense to go with the flow.

Does it really make sense to use getters and setters for every property in Java? If you understand the domain you're using well, it very well might not. But stop doing it and your code isn't going to make sense to other members of your team, you'll have to continuously revisit the decision as people join, and so forth.

If it's a one-person project and always will be, of course, you can do what you want.

Comment: I'm not saying we shouldn't adhere to conventions, I'm just saying 99% of the times it doesn't make sense. Even if a library collide, just use the SHORT qualified package name, and prefer emphasizing your code. As I wrote in my question, with short hierarchies it's easier, and even pretty, to specify the qualified name.
And as you wrote, this convention was born twenty years ago, might be time to think a little bit more about what we do.